# First Chern class of endomorphism bundle on a $K3$ surface

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $E$ be a rank $r$ bundle on a $K3$ surface. The formulas of the Chern classes for $E \otimes L$ where $L$ is a line bundle are well known.

Question : Do there exist similar formulas for Chern classes of $E \otimes E^* = \mathcal Hom (E,E)$? In particular, what are $c_1(\mathcal{H}om(E,E))$ and $c_2((\mathcal {H}om(E,E))$?

Can someone give me any reference?

Any help from anyone is welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One reference would be Hirzebruch's *Topological Methods in Algebraic Geometry*. The way to work it out is with the splitting principle, assuming that $E$ splits as a sum of line bundles, $E=\oplus_{j=1}^r L_j$. If $c_1(L_j)=\delta_j$, then you write $c(E) = \prod_{j=1}^r (1+\delta_j)$.  Then $c(E^*) = \prod_{k=1}^r (1-\delta_k)$ and $c(E\otimes E^*) = \prod_{j,k} (1+\delta_j-\delta_k)$.

Now you just have to write things out and count carefully. It might be easier to keep score if you do $c(E\otimes F) = \prod_{j,k} (1+\delta_j+\eta_k)$ and specialize later to $F=E^*$.